Does 5F4(5) Hypergeometric exist?
Fairly straightforward. On the Wikiedia for Askey Scheme the highest-order hypergeometric shown is 4F3(4) (Racah).
I am wondering if higher variate and order hypergeometrics such as 5F$(5) exist as well and if there are any resources on it.

In the Wikipedia article Askey scheme  the Completeness section states: "While there are several approaches to constructing still more general families of orthogonal polynomials, it is usually not possible to extend the Askey scheme by reusing hypergeometric functions of the same form. " There is a reference to a 2009 paper.

@Somos does that mean different coefficients or a different method entirely?

The Wikipedia article is very brief. I suggest search the web for other sources of informaiton.

@Somos That's why I asked on here because I couldn't find anything.
